# Bootstrap 3 Understanding navbar-collapse and nav navbar-nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is the segment of the code of navbar menu:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse2">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li I .... </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What defines the width of the ul class "nav navbar-nav"?  When I view the page in the Development Tools I see the items (li) but I cannot figure out what defines the width.

The reason I am asking is I have 4 "li" items (3 anchors and one asp:LoginStatus control). And in the IE all 4 items are in one line; which is what I want. But when I look at the page in the Chrome, the last items (asp:LoginStatus) breaks into the next line.  And this is all on a large monitor.

I realize that his has something to do with how Bootstrap 3 works in webkit engine but I can't figure how to custom change it.  Could it be that in Chrome UL properties are in "user agent stylesheet"?

Resolved the issue by setting inline style of UL to "width:900px."  But it would nice to know why - before this property was overridden - the width of the UL was 612px.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question is older, but the best way to figure out issues like this are to use the browser tools to find out from which class the styles are getting set.

In your case, and I wasn't able to reproduce it here (perhaps due to minor version bumps and bug fixes), I can see that the width is not explicitly set on a `nav navbar-nav ul' element, so it's being propagated from the combined widths of the child controls.

This is usually a symptom of some other property of the child elements being set (such as additional padding or margins) that isn't expected by Bootstrap itself. It could also be that a container element has been inadvertently left without a closing tag.  You can now use the super-handy [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) checker to ensure that your document structure and classes are as Bootstrap expects, even add it to your CI process.